# Read a CSV file and writer into a file without " " using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file and stored all the values in the single list.CSV file contains credentials as uid(userid) and pass(password) and separated by','I have successfully read all the lines and write it in the file.but when it writes in the file, it write the value in between " "(double quotes) like as("abcdefgh3 12345678")what i want actually to remove this "" double quotes sign when i write it in to the files.i am pasting my code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{

var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Desktop\userid1.csv"));

List<string> listA = new List<string>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {

                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                listA.Add(values[0]);
               listA.Add(values[1]);
            }

            foreach (string a in listA)
            {
                TextWriter tr = new StreamWriter(@"E:\newfiless",true);
                tr.Write(a);
                tr.Write(tr.NewLine);
                tr.Close();
            }
        }
```

and the resulted output is like this:

"uid

pass"

"Martin123

123456789"

"Damian

91644"

but i want in this form:

uid

pass

Martin123

123456789
Damian

91644

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: can you check, if values which you are reading have double quote or not.

Comment: and what does the csv file looks like? , there is nothing in your code that adds the double quotemarks

Comment: Your code works without adding quotes but you are doing really strange thing - you create new StreamWriter for each row in your csv file. Why don't you just create it once, write to it within a loop and then close?

Comment: The original file clearly contains the quotes. You can `Trim` (or `TrimEnd`/`TrimStart`) them away, but I'd rather check the original file generation.

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with the double-quotes, but why are you opening and closing the output file for each piece of data you're writing? Note that reading CSV is a _lot_ more complicated than just splitting on commas. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: And note that a good code example will be _entirely_ self-contained, including any input data.

Comment: ok i got what you are saying. I should not create object every time and should not open and close the file, every time i am writing into it. But neglecting those things can you help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The original file clearly has quotes, which makes it a CSV file with only one colum and in that column there are two values. Not usual, but it happens.

To actually remove quotes you can use [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `TrimEnd` or `TrimStart`.

You can remove the quotes while reading, or while writing, in this case it doesn't really matter.

```
var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim('"');
```

This will remove the quotes while reading. Note that this assumes the CSV is of this "broken" variant.

```
tr.WriteLine(a.Trim('"'));
```

This will handle it on write. This will work even if the file is "correct" CSV having two columns and values in quotes.

Note that you can use `WriteLine` to add the newline, no need for two `Write` calls.

Also as others have commented, don't create a `TextWriter` in the loop for every value, create it once.

```
using (TextWriter tr = new StreamWriter(@"E:\newfiless"))
{
    foreach (string a in listA)
    {
        tr.WriteLine(a.Trim('"'));
    }
}
```

The `using` will take care of closing the file and other possible resources even if there is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all you need to read the input file, strip out all starting/ending quotation marks, then split by comma and write it all to another file. You can actually accomplish it in a one-liner using `SelectMany`, which will produce a "flat" collection:

```
File.WriteAllLines( 
    @"c:\temp\output.txt", 
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\input.csv")
        .SelectMany(line => line.Trim('"').Split(','))
);
```

It's not quite clear from your example where quotation marks are located in the file. For a typical .CSV file some comma-separated field might be wrapped in quotation marks to allow commas to be a part of the content. If it's the case, then parsing will be more complex.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
tr.Write(a.Substring(1, line.Length - 2));
```

Edited

Please use Trim

```
tr.Write(a.TrimEnd('"').TrimStart('"'));
```

Comment: And what if the file suddenly doesn't have quotes? And this will strip one extra character since only the beginning or ending has a quote. Why not `Trim`?

Comment: Agree. Trim should be used. Editing the answer.